# Make companion stop following without knowing where they are

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a person following me but I lost here somewhere and she hasn't returned.  When I try to get a *new* person to follow me, I get the "looks you already have someone with you" when I don't.  How can I force a person with unknown whereabouts to leave me?

Comment: Anybody know if there are console commands that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your follower isn't around anymore, [they most likely went home](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/your-follower-tires-of-waiting-and-leaves-how-do-i-get-my-stuff-back). Go back there and you should see them again, allowing you to summarily dismiss them for the cowardly and lazy follower that they are.

Comment: I've been trying to get Lydia to follow me, she's sitting in the Dragonreach with the Jarl, but everytime I ask her to follow me, she replies with "Looks like you've already got someone with you." Haven't tried fast traveling yet, but is there anything else I can do to make her follow me?

Comment: @ManishGill: You have to find the follower you currently have and tell them to stop following you.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this because I was on the Companion quest 'Proving Honor'.  I forgot that Farkas was waiting at the dungeon entrance for me, and apparently even though I'm not actually with him yet, this counts as a follower.  So watch out for that and similar quest partners.

Comment: +1 for this. Just ran into this exact issue with Farkas.

Answer (score 2):

Try fast traveling. It worked for me once.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about lydia, happened to me too; sometimes she'll appear in whiterun if you buy the house, you lost her cause of the initiaiton quest with the companions, I got a feeling once you do that mission she'll come back too but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: I think I issued her to wait somewhere, but didn't know where or didn't want to make the effort to retrieve her. *Eventually* I got the the message "Your companion tires of waiting and leaves" but I wanted to speed up the process.