# How do I find Lydia if I've lost her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

I just finished the quest *Diplomatic Immunity*, but for some reason, Lydia (my current follower) is nowhere to be found.

I'd like to find her: she has all of my gear! If a follower like Lydia disappears, where can I find him or her?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking back in Dragonsreach i think. Whatever city you picked her up in...OR...if you own a house check there.  I was in the wild and told her to go away I didnt need her help and she showed up in Breezehome...the only home i own and use.  It may or may not matter but i got married for the extra gold income and my spouse lives there with Lydia.

Make sure you didn't tell her to stay somewhere because I did that and forgot about it. So if you had told her to stand somewhere and didn't tell her to follow you again go get her she's waiting for you.

Comment: i checked there an she is no where to be found aswell as i donnot have a house yet have enough cash tp biuy one justr havent yet

Comment: even though you dont own it check breeze home...its supposed to be a place she lives in. usually up stairs to the right.