# How do I get a companion when it thinks I already have someone but I don't?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had my companion with me on the mission "Forsworn Conspiracy" and after completing the mission they vanished.  I figured 'oh well, I'll go get a different companion', but when I tried they were all saying that it:

> Looks like you already have someone.

I tried fast-traveling and waiting to no avail.  How can I fix this error?

Comment: In my case I lost my companion, but when I returned to the keep in Winterhold she was waiting for me there. As long as the game thinks you still have one, then you should be able to find her (somewhere!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

Comment: @Drake this isn't a duplicate; this has to deal with an apparent bug; that one is recovering one that lost themselves.  Additionally, the resolution attempts to that question that the asker tried failed.

Comment: I have this same problem (PC version). It's been several in-game weeks she's been saying this, so I don't think my supposed companion is going to "get bored" anytime soon.

Comment: [Do you have any quests from The Companions in your log? If so, this may be a duplicate.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/skyrim-you-already-have-a-follower-issue)

Comment: Depending on the follower, if you kill an "innocent" person, they might leave you;)

Comment: Related: [How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44880/4797)

Answer (score 6):

Your companion must be stuck somewhere during the mission, if you wait a couple of days, you should get a message telling you that your companion got bored and went home. Then, you should be able to recruit a new companion

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you get a quest where you have to meet someone somewhere. Just do that/those quest/s and any you'll be able to have followers.

Answer (score 1):

Try dying and then see what happens when you come back. If that doesn't work, try turning the game off and reloading it. If that doesn't work, just go back a save point (if it wasn't too far).

Answer (score 1):

I would go to the place where your companion would be if they went your active companion.  Perhaps they will be there and it is a glitch that makes the game think they are following you but aren't.  If they are there I would try to recruit them and see if that fixes anything.

I would wiki or google search to see where your "lost" friend is located when they are not following you actively. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remember his name search for his name on the site below and figure out his character code.

[Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) is all you need to know about console commands.

Open console and enter **player.placeatme *characterCode*** (enter his code you found instead).

This should get him to you,if he is dead enter **prid characterCode**(to select him) than write  **Resurrect** after you can use the first code to bring him to you.

Note : You might need to use **Disable** command to remove some things from game completely or use **moveto** to get to them.

If something is still wrong read the wiki good there is bunch of commands to do almost anything,just figure out what will work best for you.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command: "*Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed.*" - http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console  Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead.

Comment: [A post of mine here in Arqade on how to use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` console commands](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).