# My follower is gone and I can't recruit a new one

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to do the Boethiah's Calling quest and I need a follower for it of course to sacrifice. But whenever I ask someone to be my follower they say I already have one. This is a problem because I don't have a follower. I had a dark brotherhood follower a month or two ago but I lost her and haven't been able to find her since. I've fast traveled and slept and tried multiple things to find her but to no avail. Now I can't get a new follower for the quest or get rid of my old one.

Comment: Hey, @cooiejr.  Don't challenge a duplicate in your question body.  Either comment on it, and flag for re-opening, or ask on Meta.  Either way, "Does not help me" is not a valid reason to re-ask a question.  Have you followed the directions in the duplicate question?

Comment: Yes all of the answers dont apply to my specific problem. For example one of linked problems the answer was they were on a companions quest which caused it to count as a follower. So all they needed to do was that quest. An answer like that doesnt help me in anyway as I finished that quest a long time ago. My question sure might be a duplicate but the solution to my problem isnt found on any of those.

Comment: @Cooiejr Have you fast-traveled in a mission, as explained here? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79584/1721. If that doesn't help you this may be worth re-opening for an answer.

Comment: [The answers to this question should prove more helpful](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

Comment: Ive tried all of those which makes me think that my game is just glitched with no solution because for 1 the dark brotherhood initiates cant die. 2 if they did I could recruit a new follower and 3 its been allot longer than 3 days since ive seen them and there not at the sanctuary.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, the follower went back home. You mentioned a female Dark Brotherhood member, which sounds like a [Dark Brotherhood Initiate](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Brotherhood_Initiate). You can probably find them in the [Dawnstar Sanctuary](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dawnstar_Sanctuary). If they're not there, wait three Skyrim days and try again.

Comment: Ive checked the sanctuary mulitple times and despite waitng and sleeping more than 3 days I cant find her anywhere.

Comment: @Cooiejr Have you tried hiring a new Initiate? it could be they've bugged out.

Comment: Yeah Ive tried that and they still say I have someone with me.

Comment: The other answer says you might've started a companions quest that makes Farkas your follower. Check Dustman's Cairn.

Comment: Saddly I finished that quest a long time ago so that cant be it :/

Comment: It's possibly an equivalent quest. Check your quest dialog.