# I can't get a follower on skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've apparently told my follower to stay put somewhere or they have died or something along those lines,I have slept and waited for days and days,I've used the dog companion fix,and ive done a mission that's fast traveled me somewhere on its on,but if I ever go to get a follower it tells me that I have a current follower and can have only one at a time

Comment: Perhaps related to this:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/skyrim-you-already-have-a-follower-issue

Answer (score 1):

- Fast travel to any place and there is a chance your follower might spawn out of nowhere like your Pets (horse or dog)
- See if you have left any mission incomplete after starting it. Some missions tend to come with followers and you may need to get rid of that follower before trying to add another.