# Skyrim - Lost my unknown follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/how-do-i-get-skyrim-to-recognize-i-dont-have-a-follower-anymore)

I lost my follower some time ago. I didnt noticed until i tried to get a new one and they told me that I allready got someone.
guess my follower is not dead, because then I could have a new one.
Problem is that I can not remember who my follower was, so I can not beam him to me with the console.
And I dont want to reload because theres too much progress going to be los then.Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can always reload to when you last had your follower, figure out who it was, then load the game to where you presently are and use the console then. I did this when I lost mine as well and it worked perfectly.

I think I left my follower in a cave somewhere to be eaten by draugr...