# Followers don't follow after I fast travel somewhere

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the recruiting for the blades after recruiting a mercenary and someone else, then I got the final recruit and fast traveled to Sky Haven Temple but my follower wasn't there.

Later I went back to Mor Khazgur (where I found her) and she was still there. I got the dialogue option to have her follow me but she said I already have a follower.

Is there a way to make followers follow when I fast travel? How can I get Mor Khazgur to follow me again?

Comment: Could you edit to clarify whether it the last person you recruited, another recruit, or just a follower you had at the start of the quest?

This is a near-duplicate of a couple other questions, [You Already Have a Follower](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/skyrim-you-already-have-a-follower-issue?s=11|1.5540) and [How Do I Get Skyrim to Recognize I Don't Have a Follower Anymore](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/how-do-i-get-skyrim-to-recognize-i-dont-have-a-follower-anymore). However, it's unclear whether either answer would apply in your case.

Comment: I'll post a tentative answer until we figure out the details..

Answer (score 2):

Some times a follower will not follow if they were in combat and you left so I recommend going back and using a calming spell to calm all enemies that can not be killed so she/he can follow

Answer (score 0):

If an NPC refuses to follow and says you already have a follower when you don't, and you can't [fix this with a console command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/how-do-i-get-skyrim-to-recognize-i-dont-have-a-follower-anymore) because you are using an XBox or PS3, you can either return to an earlier save or wait/sleep somewhere for three days, after which you should get a message that your follower has left your service. If neither option works, you can try fast-travelling a couple times to see if you are joined by a follower, after which you can dismiss the follower normally.