# Can't get followers after Riekling follower died

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried to get a riekling, so I left my follower then got the riekling. My follower went out of the place and disappeared.

I went to where I got her and tried getting her again, but she said "You already have a follower". However, my riekling died earlier. Now I can't get any followers.

Help me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44880/4797)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per galacticninja's comment to get this into the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on PC you can use this command:

> set playerfollowercount to 0

It will set your follower count to zero, and you should then be able to pick up a new follower.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the companions quest line, Farkas will have a topic which will start a quest and he will be a follower replaced.

Comment: This actually caused this issue for me. My other follower left and Farkas never properly joined.  Now it thinks I have a follower when I don't.

Answer (score 0):

What I can offer is you can finish one companions quest then go to a different one and hope there auto follow kicks in,

Comment: There is no mention of a companion quest, nor is there an auto-follow function in Skyrim. Can you elaborate?