# I lost my follower Marcurio and then he returned back to The Bee and Barb?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the quest to kill the Ice Wraith to join the Stormcloaks, when I left my follower, Marcurio, on the side of a cliff, because he was getting in the way.

After I completed the quest, I went back to find him but I couldn't. So, I went back to Riften and found him at the Bee and Barb, where I recruited him. When I speak to him, he acts like I've got a follower and says "looks like you've got someone already" and stuff like that.

How do I fix this so he is following me again?

Comment: Are you on PC or a console? These questions might help: [Skyrim "You already have a follower" issue](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44581), [How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44880)

Comment: I presume you have tried talking to him at the Bee and Barb? What does he say, or are you even able to get into dialog options?

Comment: When I speak to him he acts like I've got a follower and says "looks like you've got someone already" and stuff like that.

Comment: Did you start any other quests between losing Marcurio and finding him again? Did you try to recruit any other followers?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on PC, then type the following command into the console (which can be opened with the ~ key):
set playerfollowercount to 0

If you are on console, then all I can say to do is to load a save.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting arrested, that works for me when one of my followers stopped following me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe load an old save? That should work

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer  a bit to explain why you think this will solve the askers problem? Thanks! :)