# Maurice Jondrelle died on me and now I can't use my companion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had this useless guy with me for a quest and he was killed by a dragon. Now my husband/Companion tells me that I already have someone with me and will not follow me. How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a companion when it thinks I already have someone but I don't?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/how-do-i-get-a-companion-when-it-thinks-i-already-have-someone-but-i-dont)

Comment: Read that, that's not it. I didn't lose him, he died.  And I have completed the quest.  Yet they still think I have one.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate in this case as Maurice is not a normal companion but just someone who asks to follow you on one specific quest. I would say the OP may just have to complete the quest to open the take someone with your option up again.

Answer (score 4):

Try teleporting Maurice to your location through console commands, and see if you can get him to unfollow you.

Console commands to teleport Maurice to the player's current location:
`prid 1C606`
`moveto player`

'prid' targets an entity - [Maurice](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maurice_Jondrelle) in this case. '1C606' is Maurice's [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs). 'moveto player' moves that targetted entity near the vicinity of the player.

Maurice's dead body, should now be near you after doing this. Use the console command `resurrect 1`. Maurice should go back to life, good as new.

If Maurice is still not near your vicinity after doing this, he may have been 'disabled' from the game. Type `enable` in the console to remedy this. If he still isn't up, type `resurrect 1` again.

Try having a conversation with him and see if you can get him to leave you.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Comment: Wow, that worked.  He's good as new he just won't talk to me. Maybe I'll wait a few game days and it will release him of me.  Love this site btw.

Comment: Trick here is to use `resurrect 1` to get him to continue following you after he's been resurrected.

Answer (score 2):

Things like that are solved by using console commands.

[Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) is all you need to know about console.

Commands you will need are:

- **player.placeatme *1C605*** (if the character code is wrong check on mentioned wiki link there is a full list).
- **Resurrect** (open console,target the companion,enter)

This should get the corpse to you than you can resurrect him and get rid of him for good.

If that doesn't work try entering **prid 1C605**(to select him) and **Resurrect** to revive him.

Note : You might need to use **Disable** command to remove some things from game completely or use **moveto** to get to them.

If something is still wrong read the wiki good there is bunch of commands to do almost anything,just figure out what will work best for you.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command - from the [UESP 'Console' article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console): "*Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed.*" Use the `prid` and `moveto` commands instead.

Comment: It should work if you use code right way or by adding space and 1 (to determine quantity of an object...or not to use it depands on problem).Still you can use DISABLE command to remove old or duplicated thing from game.

Comment: The duplicate copy of Maurice made by `placeatme` will not have the scripts of the original. What died was the original Maurice, and it is the original that should be teleported using `moveto player`. `placeatme` will just spawn a *copy*, not teleport the original.

Comment: Duplicate will have the exact script as the first one(according to wiki) and that's why you should be able to get rid of duplicate and fool the game,weird as it is sounds people managed to do this.

Comment: Can I remove Maurice?

Comment: Well I did disable him since he still wouldn't leave me but my companion still won't follow me.  Not sure what to do, but wait??

Comment: That's because you directly removed him from game it didn't triggered the "bug"...you need to let him go easy by conversation...use KILL/RESURRECT or ENABLE/DISABLE commands to "refresh" Maurice into dialogue.

Comment: you can also use this "player.setrelationshiprank <actor> <value>" if you have dialogue problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all you have to do is to write in console **set playerfollowercount to 0**