# Lost riekling follower (PS3)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a reikling as a follower and I told it to wait (in whiterun I think, I checked and it's not there.) now I cannot accept another follower and I'm one of those people who like to collect cool weapons and it's really putting a damper on my collecting. Help?

Comment: Also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/how-do-i-get-a-companion-when-it-thinks-i-already-have-someone-but-i-dont

Answer (score 0):

Fast travel somewhere, he could be stuck when he tried to follow you or something. He should be with you when you fast travel, if not, try reloading a save and he might appear.