# I lost my follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

When I was asked to get a knife from some crazy witch to save a tree I lost my follower. There was no body, she didn’t die, and my friend said the same thing happened to her. So, is this a glitch? Is anyone else having this problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried fast-travelling back to your house, and checking there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `fast-travel` to any place and, if your follower didn't respawn near you there are three possible Issues:

> 1. Your follower died (sorry it's bad news)
> 2. It's a bug (nice one)
> 3. You told him/her to wait and forgot where or can't return to where you told them to wait  (bad loop-hole)

Comment: Well I've fast traveled and gone back and looked for a body, so I think I found a bug. thanks

Comment: Note: if you tell your follower to wait and *don't* get back to them, they will *eventually* (after a few days) return to their "home" (what that is depends on the follower).

Comment: ...and you will get a message about how they got tired of waiting.

Comment: @JoachimSauer are you sure about that? I told Lydia to wait in Markarth, forgot about that, did some quests without her and returned after about 6 or 7 days when I noticed she's gone, and she was still there.

Answer (score 0):

This actually happened to me. I was sure she was dead, then I bought a house and a day after decorating it I walked in and she was sitting at the table in my bedroom. 
So, she may turn up!

Comment: until you haven't any house, your follower can be fount in first place you meet him/her. (specially Lydia can be found in `The Jarl's palace, Dragonsreach`)

Comment: Lydia is the one I lost, and she didn't go home. I got her with the house and I had her from then on. Now she is gone, so I think it is a bug. My friend had the same thing happen 2 days before it happened to me.