# What happened to Lydia?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

In Skyrim, I got Lydia and then I did the quest to become a companion.  Farkas replaced Lydia, and then when I was done with the quest, Farkas stopped being my follower, but Lydia never came back.  What happened?

Answer (score 5):

I did the same, doing quest with Farkas after having Lydia as a follower.
When back from the quest, she was waiting for me in my house in Whiterun, in the bedroom (!). If you didn't buy the house, I suppose she should be where you found her first, being in Dragonsreach near the front door.

edit:
[UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lydia) seems to confirm this.
Otherwise, check [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/i-lost-my-follower); she may be dead even if she should have stayed in Whiterun.
Can you take another follower? If so, she's probably dead by now... Sorry for your loss.

Comment: No, I looked there, and nobody could say anything about her.  It's almost as if she never exsisted.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought the house in Whiterun, she'll be in there. If not, she's in Dragonreach, but she walks around in there in multiple areas, so you'll have to look around. I went there once and she was at the center table, but when I came back she was walking around in the northern room.

If she's not in either of those two places, she died and you won't be able to get her back unless you load a previous save where you know she's alive.

Answer (score 1):

If your are playing on PC you can try this command : "a2c94.moveto player" to move here to your location.

Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lydia)

Comment: I have it for Xbox 360.

Comment: A friend of mine had the same bug. But I have no idea how to fix it on a console, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

in skyrim you can have only one follower at any time.
so because Farkas is the quest follower it caused lydia to leave.
now after Farkas left you can have a follower (Lydia) she will be at Breezehome (if you bought it),
or she will be in dragonsreach.