# Lost Skyrim Follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/i-lost-my-follower)

Ok, so I had J'zargo and Meeko. I just started "A Daedra's Best Friend" and was following Barbas. So we were walking and then got attacked. During the confusion, I saw Meeko walk off up a hill. I never saw him again. I need help, because I know he's not dead as I checked every corner of the area and did not find his body, he might be stuck, considering he's not with me (duh), and when I checked his shack, he was not there and neither was his owner. If someone could help, I'd appreciate it, as Meeko was awesome. :(

Comment: The fastest way is fast traveling somewhere - if he was just stuck he would appear besides you.

Comment: Or wait for an hour