# What happend to my follower, Lydia, with all my stuff?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)
>   [I lost my follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/i-lost-my-follower)

So I am pretty far in the game, and is currently completing the Stormcloack questline. I approach to liberate Whiterun and get rid of those Imperial troops. Lydia is there fighting with me, and once I got to the Jarl, she goes of to his side (So she is clearly not dead) Then I do listen to the talking with the Jarl and stuff and walk away. Next thing I know, Lydia is gone and I can't find her at all. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Try going back into the Jarl's quarters and the rest of the keep and try talking to her again if you find her. Lydia is originally found in there, so the game may have tried to keep her there after it moved her. If you can't find her, try looking in your player-owned houses if you have any, as many followers return there if you tell them to leave.