# My spouse disappeared while adventuring together

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I married Onmund a while back, and I guess I told him to wait in the orphanage after murdering Grelod (not sure why I did that) and then found him there. I've kept him as a follower since then, and we just raided Fort Snowhawk together. After clearing the place out we started making our way to Solitude where I passed the apprentice stone (he's still following at this point) and about the same distance from the fort and apprentice stone but in the direction of solitude I found an abandoned camp and took a book from it. This was too much to carry so I turned around to give some things to Onmund but he's suddenly gone! I know he was with me at LEAST until we got to the apprentice stone, and we didn't fight anything between the stone and abandoned campsite. I don't see him anywhere, and it's too damn slow to go anywhere without dropping my loot (most of which i plan to sell). I last had my horse near the college of winterhold, and god knows where he wandered off to (closest stable to there is windhelm I think) so I can't go anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea of how to either find him, use a console command to bring him to me, or is this a scripted event that I didn't know about? This just happened now so I haven't done much (any) troubleshooting myself before searching online, where I didn't find any answers quickly.

Comment: The second answer there by gameaddict will help you with console commands on how to bring your follower back to you.

Comment: @Virusbomb I thought the same about the duplicate but that question technically is about the follower explicitly leaving the player after x days have passed. This question refers to the follower becoming lost. That being said, the answer you referenced does indeed help this OP.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with any follower and it's quite common, so don't worry too much. As specified in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38763/186876) there's a few reasons for this:

> 1. Your follower died (sorry it's bad news)
> 2. It's a bug (nice one)
> 3. You told him/her to wait and forgot where or can't return to where you told them to wait (bad loop-hole)

I'll start with the most likely scenario: **it's a bug and/or problem with pathing**. He's gotten stuck and can't get to you. There two ways to deal with this; wait for an hour or two (ideal since you are over-encumbered) or fast travel somewhere nearby (like The Apprentice Stone). If your over-encumbered fast travel isn't an option but if it's only the book that's pushing you over your limit you can drop it to the ground and hold it using the "grab" key, then fast travel while holding it and it'll stay with you. Fast travelling usually works better to fix this.

If he still isn't there he's most likely dead (sorry, that was a bit blunt, we are talking about your husband after all). While you may not have been involved in a fight, Onmund may well have gotten too close to an enemy and engaged, and possible died, all without you knowing. As I mentioned, the game has issues with pathing and the route Onmund took could have taken him too close to a nearby enemy. If his health was low from Snowhawk this is even more likely. In this case either find him and mourn, or if you aren't ready to say goodbye just reload a save.

Still can't find him? Time to use the console (I tend to use this last as it really breaks immersion). You can use the command `prid 0001C1A2` to "select" Onmund in the console, then `moveto player` to bring him to you.

If he still refuses to obey his spouse then reload a previous save. And keep an eye on him this time. These Nords have a tendency to stray.