# In Skyrim, I told my follower to stay somewhere, but I've forgotten where. How can I find him?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I lost my follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

At first I had Janessa following me, and then I couldn't find her.  I fast traveled and went into dungeons and she was no where to be found.  So I assumed she had died, even though I really don't think she did.  So then I had Benor following me, and now the same thing has happened.  I think I might have told them to wait somewhere, but I can't remember where I told them to wait.  Is there any way I can locate them?  I had Benor carrying some stuff I wanted to sell :/ I really want it back.

- By the way, I looked at other questions/answers involving lost followers and none address the possibility of having left them on the "stay here" command.

Comment: I'd say it's not really the same question. I lost my follower is talking about what Christina originally did (the whole losing them for no reason). This question is asking what to do if you tell your follower to wait and then you forget where they are, so I'm voting to reopen it.

Comment: Did you go back to the Drunken Huntsman to find her, did you check the Whiterun Stables?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PC you can use the console command `player.moveto 0001AA65`

If you are using console try saving, restarting and reloading the game (use a new save slot).

You can also try fast traveling to another location, your follower should follow you even if they are not in the surrounding area.

Another option is to go to your home and search there.

Finally you could try waiting a couple of days and head back to where you originally found your companion, you may find him sleeping in his bed or just staying there.

If none of that works, he may have been killed, you could resurrect any companion, but I doubt it will come back with your items. For extra advice try to save often and with different saves. :) Good luck.

you can resurrect your follower with the items it has or without 
(resurrect 1) with items 
(resurrect) without 
just remove "()" and make sure to click them.

Comment: Thanks for the player.moveto command it didn't exactly work for me but I found on this site http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lydia the ID of my follower which was Lydia: Ref ID 000A2C94 . So I did player.moveto 000A2C94 and there she was in a dungeon where I apparently told her to wait.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the wait command for a few days (default T on PC) then eventually "Your follower tires of waiting and leaves". Then all you have to do is go back to where you originally got them to follow you, and they'll be there.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found Janessa, but still no sign of Benor.  I'll check again for him later and see if he turns up.

Comment: Note that they may also go to your house instead, which made me run around between where I lost my follower and where I found her for quite a while, until I read this.