# What can I do if Shadowmere died and I don't know where?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What if Shadowmere died and I forget where he died at? Is there a way to easily find him?

I have tried to find out where he died several times but I have come up short in nothing but a couple of angry bandit raids and one or two dragon fly by's.

Comment: Since when can Shadowmere die? I always thought he is almost, if not completely, immortal.

Comment: @VascovdEng She can die for a while having around 1600 health or so, if the battle goes long enough with enough damage .. pft Dead... She more often dies from fall damage though.

Comment: @James huh, didn't knew that. I lost my Shadowmere anyway like ± 100 in-game hours ago for some random reason. Haven't been able to find it since. Thanks for the intel.

Comment: Related: [I've lost Shadowmere - where can I find her?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/40925/4797)

Answer (score 2):

Shadowmere is actually a unique horse and will not stay dead, but it may take some time for her to respawn. The easiest place to check would be by the pool where you found her as all horses will tend to go 'home' when left alone for a long period of time.

Note that there -is- a bug that will cause Shadowmere to not respawn but so far everyone I have seen play Skyrim and actually manage to kill Shadowmere in the first place has also had her reappear, it just takes a bit of time is all.

NOTE: Shadowmere is referred to as a Him and a Her at different points in the game and was always a her in oblivion... sooo. I just call him a her.

Comment: Given that the word the "mere" in "Shadowmere" appears to be cognate to "mare", indicating that she is indeed a her. On the other hand, it's not entirely clear that gender is a thing that necessarily applies to an immortal demon horse, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can get her back from the pool where you found her. Sometimes, she'll respawn after waiting in the last Stables you travelled to.
Alternatively on PC :

```
prid 9CCD8
moveto player
```