# Skyrim companion lost

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

So I became the thane of whiterun and got my first companion and she traveled around with me until I got bored and started killing the whiterun guards. I accidentally took on the jarl and his men. After winning and running away, I couldn't find her anymore. I wouldn't care but she had 3 dragons worth of bones and scales on her. I didn't tell her to stay anywhere either, any suggestions on where I need to look? I've also conquered whiterun for the stormcloaks, will that prevent me from getting her back?

Comment: Did she attack you? Maybe she did and you killed her while fighting guards thus didn't notice. Look for her body in  the city where you fought the guards.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought the house in Whiterun check there. If not, check all the rooms in Dragonreach.  If you still can't find her, try the console.

Comment: I never bought the house, never had enough money