# I dismissed Jenassa, now I can't find her at the drunken huntsman where she asked to meet me. I want my 500 gold back!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

I paid Jenassa 500 gold and hired her as a companion. This was before I became the thane of Dragonsreach. I was really happy with Jenassa and only dismissed her because I wanted to see if Lydia was any good as a companion.

The problem is that before leaving she said "You can find me at the tavern". I guessed that meant the Drunken Huntsman (where I originally found her).

But she's nowhere to be found. I've tried all sorts of things like leaving Dragonsreach for three days and then returning, entering the Drunken Huntsman at all times of the day, etc.

What gives?

Comment: Have you tried waiting or sleeping for several days to pass before visiting the Drunken Huntsman? Make sure NOT to visit the tavern for a long period of time. Maybe there's a timer that resets if you go and check in everyday. Also perhaps leave Whiterun altogether for that period.

Comment: @Dave: No, it is not. My condition is not part of any explanation in the selected answer.

Comment: @faB: I did try things similar to what you suggest. Nothing worked

Comment: @Dave: To explain: She didn't die. She walked out of the Jarl's castle and disappeared. She didn't bug out. Fast travelling didn't make her reappear (as I had already dismissed her). She wasn't 'home' at the Drunken huntsman.

Comment: If the issue is that an existing question covers your situation but does not address it in the answer, then I believe the site is better served by improving that answer, either by asking that person "What if none of those things apply?" or by updating the answer yourself if you figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

You may be suffering from a bug, which causes her to show up by the WhiteRun stables.

However, based on the description of the bug, it was from her being dismissed when doing the Companion quest Proving Honor, and she only shows up at the stables after doing Battle for WhiteRun.

It might be worth a check to she if she's there, though.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to include the link I found this info on:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Jenassa

Check out the bottom in the glitches section. It describes it fairly thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joseph, I looked all around whiterun and dragonsreach, but not outside, near the stables. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I am SO late in getting back to you, but I finally found her. Somehow she fell into the moat outside the whiterun castle (the one where you can take the staircase into it) and was just standing there. I had to jump into the water and kind of nudge her towards the stairs and that's where her AI kicked in and she walked back to the pub.