# Why aren't the console commands "moveto" and "placeatme" working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I'm not sure when did this happen, but all of sudden I cannot use the console command `moveto` and `placeatme`.

I realized this when I'm trying to summon a dragon with `player.placeatme EAFB4`, it's just not appearing. The same happens when I'm trying to move myself to Lydia using `prid A2C94` then `moveto player`.

I have tried summoning/moving to other NPCs but it's still doesn't work.

But oddly when I tried it on another save file (different character) it's working perfectly.

Any help here? :/

---

After several tries, I have found something.

They are still spawning. But instead spawning next to me, they are spawning to somewhere below the Riften Thieves Guild (The Ragged Flagon).

I don't know why is it happening. I discovered it when I clicked my character (0000014) and then typed `moveto player` in the console command. It teleported me to the below Riften Thieves Guild. Here are some screenshots to illustrate what I mean:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

The Riften Guard and Whiterun Guard I've summoned earlier also seem to appear on that place. I tried summoning other NPCs using the `player.placeatme` again, and yup. They do appear on the Ragged Flagon.

Anyone knows why is it happening? :/

Comment: Are you carrying too much stuff?

Comment: Yes, I'm always carrying too much stuff. The command still worked earlier, but yesterday I just realized it didn't work anymore.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Did you try it without any mods running?

Comment: I have many mods. I'm not sure if mod is the cause, as in another save file (with the same mod running), I can perfectly use those console commands.

Comment: OK I have found something... they are still spawning, but instead of spawning next to me, they are spawning to the Ragged Flagon. Why is it happening?

Comment: What is the result of `GetInCellParam <ID of Riften cell> 14` while you are physically elsewhere?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I have realized that everytime I sell something to a merchant NPC... my coordinate CHANGES along with my sold items. I don't know precisely which item done this, because it just changes with every items.

The first time was in Riften. Then it happened in Markarth. Then in Windehlm. Then in Solitude.

Though it seems this problem never happen in outdoor, always in walled town. Not sure why is this happening. Should I open a new question?

Comment: Yes. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 6):

`PlaceAtMe` will create a copy of the NPC.

Instead:

- If you can see the NPC, select them with your mouse. This will show the `refId` just above the console.
- If you don't know where they are, type `prid XXXXX` (where `XXXXX` is npc `refId`)
- If you don't know the `refId` you can either:

  - save your game, load a previous save, select the NPC and write down the `refId`
  - locate it by searching one of the Skyrim wikis (like [Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com))
  - type `help <npc name>` which gives you the *base* id and you need to convert that to the `refId`.

Then, type `moveto player`. This will only work if npc is alive: if it isn't, first type `disable` then `enable` then `resurrect 1`.

Alternatively, if you want to go to the NPC, type `player.moveto XXXXX`, where `XXXXX` is the NPC `refId`.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command: "*Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed.*" - http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console.  [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands whenever possible, instead.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797)

Comment: "convert that to therefId" - how???

Answer (score 1):

Use `Player.PlaceAtMe <BaseID> [amount]` to place/spawn an item or actor object next to the player. The `[amount]` is optional. E.g., `Player.PlaceAtMe AED40 5` spawns 5 "Adoring Fans" next to the player. This only works with NPC, creature, and item IDs.

`Player.MoveTo <refID>` Teleports you the to the object associated with the RefID. This also only works with NPC, creature, and item IDs.

If you want to move an object to the player, use `<refID>.MoveTo Player`. E.g., Moving Lydia to the player would be `A2C94.MoveTo Player`.

You can look up an object's base/ref ID [here](http://www.skyrimsearch.com/npcs.php).

Comment: Sorry, that was I meant. I mean `placeatme` not `moveto` (for spawning item/actor). And yes, that still does not work.