# What happened to my Companion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

So I was in the middle of the story quest, where you must travel to the top of the mountain to meet the leader of the Greybeards. My Companion was right behind me, but when I got to the top of the mountain, she was gone, and I couldn't find a body anywhere. I also checked my house in Solitude where she was my housecarl, but she wasn't there either. Any ideas on where she could be? Or, if she is dead, is there any way of recovering my stuff?

Comment: I remember there were several monsters on the way up there.. some pretty strong (Ice Troll) - maybe she engaged in a fight and didn't survive which means the monster did survive. So go along the same path again looking for monsters, her body will probably be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to using console commands, you can try the following.

First, look up your companion on the UESP wiki.  The most common example is [Lydia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lydia). Her refid is 000A2C94.

Open the console using `, then type:

```
a2c94.moveto player
```

This should move Lydia's body to you, which you can then salvage your gear from.  I once lost Lydia and used the above command, and a pile of ash was transported to me.  I was still able to get my gear back.