# I can't find Louis Letrush

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I beat off all the mercenaries in Black Briar lodge and rode away to safety on Frost with his lineage papers.  I followed the quest marker to where I was supposed to meet Louis (a little north of Riften), and nothing.  I can't find him anywhere.  Do I need to wait for a certain time of day?  I told Maven Black-Briar of the plot.  Would that have an effect?  I want to finish this quest.

UPDATED:  So after fast traveling to a new city, to see if that would trigger him to show up, the prompt for Frost now says "Ride Frost" instead of "Steal Frost."  Does that mean I can no longer finish the mission?

Comment: UESP wiki says not telling Maven about it will cause the Black-Briar family to hate you.

Comment: "So I beat off all the mercenaries in Black Briar lodge" priceless choice of words..

Answer (score 3):

Louis Letrush may disappear if you talk to Sibbi Black-Briar before accepting Louis deal. The solution described by [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Promises_to_Keep) will require you to go back a few saves if you're not on PC.

> Reveal the plan to Maven_Black-Briar and continue the quest as normal.
>   In order to trigger Louis' appearance, you must steal the papers which
>   will be unmarked. Speaking to Maven may cause the "steal the papers"
>   portion of the quest to be marked complete, and you'll even receive a
>   notice that you've accepted the papers but if they are not in your
>   inventory then you must steal them from the lodge or the quest cannot
>   be completed.

In case you are playing on PC you can use [console commands](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) - case sensitive - to place him by your side or move to his position, respectively.

> player.placeatme 13368 1

or

> player.moveto 19DCA

Comment: Yeah, I got the quest competed when I spoke with Maven, but I still went and stole the actual papers.  I didn't think that passage meant anything other than a reminder that you still had to steal the papers.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` console command: Using that command will instantly summon an instance (a copy) of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named objects or NPCs. That command creates a new copy of an object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Comment: What if Louis is really nowhere to be found? I have the papers, I have Frost, I've spoken with Mavis, I've spoken with Devlin, I've spoken with Sibbi, but can't find Louis anywhere. There's no quest marker when I select this quest. I've tried to move to Louis, but then end up in the Bee and Barb, where he isn't at either. Checked all rooms. Looks like he's dead in my game. I thought Louis was an important NPC that couldn't die?
Skyrim 1.9 on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got it to work was by creating a new copy of him (player.placeatme -his ID) when he spawns in the quest continues normally.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the black briar lodge, kill all the mercenaries and go to the basement where you should find a table with a paper (frost's paper). I don't specifically know where the table is but it can be easily found. Once you stole the paper the quest will tell you to steal frost and then meet up with him. I haven't found him there though but I just waited until 10:00 am he just suddenly appeared out of nowhere. That's all I know but I'm not quite sure if it would work for you.