# Why won't my follower follow me after the "A Night to Remember" quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At the end of the "A Night to Remember" quest line, my follower came with me when I was teleported to the Misty Grove. Once there, I told my follower to wait.

Now, when I was teleported back to the real world, my follower's not with me: presumably because he's still waiting at the Misty Grove. I've waited for some time and still he hasn't come back.

How can I get my follower back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

Comment: Also if he is literaly glitched horribly are you on PC or Console? This makes a big difference because there are many more possibilities to fix the issue on PC than on console.

Comment: @Emerica. This isn't a duplicate of that question, although the answer to this question (wait until your follower gets tired and leaves) leads into it.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Seems to be the same concept to me. Lost my follower. How do I get them back?

Comment: @Emerica its not a dupe since the misty grove isn't a standard dungeon with a door to skyrim.  Its literally on a different plane of oblivion with no direct path back.

Comment: Btw. to test this you could rest for 3 days. (just to see if it works.)

Answer (score 3):

If told to wait, a follower will wait for about 3 days before they get tired and leave the player. They will then return to their home, or the location where they were originally found.

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Follower_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: the issue here is, is it possible for the follower to return home from that other dimension?  Since the end of the quest takes place in one of the daedric princes' world.

Comment: I think the follower does only try to walk if the cell is loaded/player is near. Wouldn't make much sense to load all the cells the follower had to cross. He probably get moved instantly. If not, you could try to teleport him by console commands. Hmm I wonder do they simulate the time the follower needs to walk the distance by using the navmesh and the followers walk speed and if that is true, do they check if there is no path at all and teleport him?

Answer (score 0):

If he doesn't come back in 3 days, you could try to go back and get him. You used to be able to get stuck in the Misty Grove if you went back after the quest, but I think they fixed it with one of the patches.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention the platform you're playing on.

If you're using a console, other answers have already suggested solutions for that:
by **[System Folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62381/4797)**
by **[Cedi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62368/4797)**

If you're playing in the PC, just use these console commands to teleport your follower to you:

Console commands to teleport your follower to the player's current location:
`prid <RefID>`
`moveto player`

`prid` targets an entity - [your follower](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) in this case. Search for your follower's RefID here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers

(*Another method to target instead of using `prid <refID>` is to open up the console and then click on an entity, this will automatically do `prid <RefID>` for the clicked entity. However, this method won't be useful in your situation as the follower is not near your vicinity, and can't be clicked on.*)

`moveto player` moves that targeted entity near the vicinity of the player.

Your follower should now be near you after doing this.  If for some weird reason, he/she is dead (happens sometimes), use the console command `resurrect 1`. Your follower should go back to life.

If for another weird reason, your follower is still not near your vicinity after doing this, he/she may have been 'disabled' from the game (might happen with NPCs that are long dead), making him/her not appear in the game. Type `enable` in the console to remedy this. If he/she still isn't up, type `resurrect 1` again.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

*Downvoter(s): Please explain the reason behind your downvote(s), so I could address them and/or edit this answer to make it better, if necessary.*

Comment: You're answering a [general question about random follower disappearances](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296), which this question isn't about. You've gone into great detail about the scenario of the follower being dead, which isn't the case here, and you've provided no solution for the console use case. The [currently top-voted answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62368/3389) is the correct solution. Even if it was about the general case and it's an exact duplicate of the earlier question, cross-posting your answer is lame: just flag it for closure.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Thanks for the reason. I believe this question is just a specific version of that general question. (I believe it's a dupe. I do not have the required reputation of casting a close vote, which I would if I have.) Notice that the current top-voted answer you linked to is similar to the answer to the more general question. The scenario being dead is just a possibility that I want to mention (oftentimes when a follower stops following you - it's because he/she's dead).

Comment: @MarkTrapp "*...you've provided no solution for the console use case*" Other answers have already provided solutions for that. (But I will edit my answer to account for that.) The question asker did not mention the platform he/she is using. Also, I didn't know that posting the same answer to two questions (non-dupe, as decided by the community) is frowned upon. I just thought that it will help the question asker.

Comment: We already have a question for the more general issue, [which you already answered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/3389). If you truly believe that your answer covers both questions without modification, then this question is an exact duplicate of the earlier question and you should flag it as such. Stack Exchange's value derives from people answering questions *directly* without added noise and tangential information: reposting the same answer without directly addressing the asker's concerns is not useful and just adds noise.

Comment: @MarkTrapp "*...reposting the same answer without directly addressing the asker's concerns is not useful...*" That wasn't what I was trying to do. I posted the easiest way (I believe) to get the follower back, if one is playing in the PC (that's what I'd do if I'm in the same situation). Anyway, I don't have the privilege to cast close votes, so should I just flag this for moderator attention? (Is it acceptable to flag for moderator attention with the reason: "I believe this question should be closed"?)

Comment: It's fine to flag a question for closure when you can't vote to close yet: go to *flag* → *it doesn't belong here* → *exact duplicate* and select the duplicate question.