# How can I intimidate Ulfberth War-Bear when Ulfberth War-Bear is dead outside my home? 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started the Companions Quest, and was told to Intimidate Ulfberth War-Bear in Whiterun. Problem is, this guy is dead and his corpse with only a loin cloth is lying outside my home in Whiterun.

What do I do now? He got killed during the war between the Imperials and the Stormcloaks, when I joined the Imperials.

Comment: I used player.placeatme 00013B9F. That gave another Ulfberth War-Bear, but the quest arrow still points to his corpse.

Comment: Have you tried resurrect?

Comment: @kotekzot resurrect worked!!! Why didn't you post an answer so I could have accepted it? Thanks for helping.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command: "*Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed.*" - http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console  [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `resurrect` in the console to bring a dead actor back to life.

Comment: might as well also add that you can use the console to set the stage of the quest to bypass the need to talk to him at all

Comment: be aware that this will not work if they are ashes (Disintegration or necromancy) or are in a coffin in the Hall of The Dead.

Comment: @tehdoommarine good point, in that case you'll probably have to `prid refID` and `enable` before doing `resurrect`.