# I can't find Lydia!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

OK so I had just become a vampire and I told Lydia to "stay here" while I snuck behind her to see if I could feed of a conscious person (turns out you can't :P). I never told her to follow me again but eventually she started following me again. 
   I thought everything was fine until she started not showing up. I wanted to give her armor so that I could take her armor at the time, and I realized she was gone. I waited, thinking she was going slow and staying behind but no Lydia. 
   I tried fast traveling to some different places but she still isn't showing up. Where is she?! I don't remember her ever dying but if she did, could she come back to life? :/

Comment: Are you playing on the PC? If yes, try [console commands to teleport and/or resurrect Lydia to your location](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797). Lydia's RefID is 'A2C94' (without the quotes).

Answer (score 2):

If you're on PC, you can open console and type `player.moveto 000A2C94`.  If she's alive, you'll be teleported to her instantly.  If she's dead, you'll find a very interesting room potentially full of dead NPCs, including Lydia who will be laying dead on the ground in her underwear.

Comment: "* If she's dead, you'll find a very interesting room potentially full of dead NPCs...*" [It's better to teleport Lydia to your location instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797) because of this. =)

Comment: But then you don't get to see dead NPCs laying around in their underwear (or less if you have the nude mod).

Comment: `prid 000A2C94`

`moveto player`

Answer (score 0):

If you tell your follower to wait somewhere, and they time out from waiting, they don't usually go back to following you. Instead, they usually go home.

Lydia's home is in Whiterun, in Dragon's Reach castle, or, if you've purchased it, Breezehome.