# Brynjolf and Brand-shei are missing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in Riften, and neither Brynjolf or Brand-Shei are around for me to initiate the Thieves Guild quest. I've tried enable/disable their npc codes, player.placeatme, I even got the Thieves Guild Requirements mod in hopes that it would jolt it back into working order. So far, nothing has worked.

I'm on the verge of reinstalling, but I wanted to ask if anybody had run into a similar situation and managed to fix it some other way.

This is my second run through the game. I had to stop playing a few months ago, so decided to start over. The Thieves Guild was one of my favorite quest lines, and I really want to get this working again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command: Using that code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named objects or NPCs. That code creates a new instance (a copy) of that object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Answer (score 3):

First, verify that you indeed can't find Brynjolf. According to http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Chance_Arrangement:

> When you come across a merchant named Brynjolf at the Riften bazaar
>   during the day or in the The Bee and Barb at night, he will propose
>   that you frame a vendor by planting a stolen ring on his person.

If you still can't find him, install the the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19) ([mirror link](http://www.darkcreations.org/forums/files/file/289-unofficial-skyrim-patch/)) and see if it fixes this.

If not, try console commands to teleport Brynjolf to the player's current location:
`prid 20545`
`moveto player`

I'd type these commands while at the Riften market area (where you're supposed to meet Brynjolf).
`prid` targets an entity - [Brynjolf](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Brynjolf)  in this case. '20545' is Brynjolf 's [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aNPCs#Console_IDs). `moveto player` moves that targetted entity near the vicinity of the player.

Brynjolf should now be near you after doing this.  If for some weird reason, he is dead (could be an effect of previous console commands tried, although unlikely as Brynjolf is 'essential'), use the console command `resurrect 1`. Brynjolf should go back to life.

If for another weird reason, Brynjolf is still not near your vicinity after doing this, he may have been 'disabled' from the game (also could be an effect of previous console commands tried), making him not appear in the game. Type `enable` in the console to remedy this. If he still isn't up, type `resurrect 1` again.

He should appear near you after typing in those commands. Try starting a conversation with him.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Answer (score 0):

Did you try talking to inn-keepers and beggars, sometimes they might give you leads. The other option is directly walking into the thieves guild and checking with Brynjolf.