# Why does my follower never get up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have a strange problem regarding followers. After my [last question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107535/do-followers-get-encumbered) it went down hill. I still have no idea what is happening to my follower.

After the last fiasco, Serana has still not returned BTW, I recruited my wife and companion Aela.

We went through the **Unearthed** quest as a follower and me. But she got hit very early on by spells. Now she is crawling everywhere. It looks like this:
[image]

This is everywhere, she never gets up.

I tried Grand Healing her, but no go. She is crawling everywhere, even in rooms that I cleared on my own (Reason I took her is to clear said rooms).

What is going on? I did install the unofficial fix to dragonborn. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are chances where the follower is stuck in a position, could be this or also in fighting stance.

Normally the best way is to load a saved game before this happened instead of continuing to play since there is a chance that this is not possible to fix.

Other options would be to do something that resets the position. I would try to use the fus-roh-dah on her to throw her over. She will then have to get up again form the floor.

The change of stance needs a trigger. So to sheath the weapons or to get up from crawling, there needs to be a change in situation that causes the trigger. If the system overlooks one trigger, the follower is stuck in the stance. You have to re-initiate a trigger to change the stance again. I am not sure what kind of attack would work since I am not sure how the follower would normally react to an attack while crawling. However a fus-ro-dah normally topples players over completely and then initiates the "get up from the ground" movement, and I am quite sure that if you manage to topple her over, she will not get into the crawling stance.

Comment: I've just had this happen with Golldir in Hillgrund's tomb - he was hurt badly in a fight and I healed him but he remained in the crawling position. Fus-ro-dah worked for me.

Comment: I verified this. I used Unrelenting Force shout on a follower who was stuck in 'Ouch'/injured mode. She stood up and said "OK let's get going"

Answer (score 3):

When this happens, try the `enable` and `disable` console commands.

Make a save game first, and then in the game, open up the [console](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>, then click on  [Aela](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aela_the_Huntress). Her [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) (0001A697) should show up in the screen. If the RefID is correct (meaning you have selected Aela correctly, and not another object), type `disable` and then `enable`.

If it doesn't work, try teleporting her to your location, to try to 'unstuck' her. With Aela still selected in the console (her [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) (0001A697) still showing up in the screen when you press <kbd>~</kbd> [if not, select her again]), type in `moveto player`.

Answer (score 1):

Have encountered this as well. The unrelenting force shout worked for me whilst other less violent methods failed.

Answer (score -4):

Ulthgerd was doing the same thing, so I bashed her with my bow.  Force them to change their stance by hitting them.