# I told Serana to wait, but can't find her anymore

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and since I have the Dragonborn DLC, I went to Soltheim and told Serana to wait or something, and now I can't find her! I'm using a ps3 and I can't use console commands, please help. I've already tried waiting but it doesn't help, and it wont let me recruit any other followers.

Comment: Did you finish Dawnguard's main quest or is it still in progress?

Comment: I *think* she should eventually get tired of waiting, and head "home", but "home" depends on how far/where you are in Dawnguard.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/59593/31508).

Comment: i have finished the danwguard quest line

Comment: Schism, ive tried those but they dont seem to work....

Comment: no, unionhawk, i have waited at least a weak and nothing happened...

Comment: Hi, Wolf, welcome to Arqade.  I've rolled back your edit because challenging a closure shouldn't be done in the question itself.  If you disagree with it being a duplicate, please clarify why it's not a duplicate, rather than just saying, "This is not a repeat" in all caps.