# Bring Heimskr back to preaching?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I "accidently" killed Heimskr, but now I miss him.
I spawned him in with the console command, but he just walks to the shrine of Talos and stands there without preaching.
His preaching is an important part of Skryim, even though some people might not like Heimskr. Does anybody know how to make him preach again?

Comment: Have you considered showing the gospel of Talos to jog his memory again? However, it's entirely possible his near permadeath experience may have made him lose faith in his god.

Comment: What console commands did you use to resurrect him?

Comment: His corpse disappeared, I had to use player.placeatme

Comment: @Xetalim Load a save before you used the player.placeatme command, then try the [`prid <RefID>`, `moveto player` and `resurrect 1` console commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to game mechanics it is entirely plausible that many interesting NPCs die.

If this upsets you and you would like to resurrect without reloading to a previous save then, naturally you can resort to console commands, as you have attempted.

There is [one fool proof guide](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/1kjlsk/pc_only_foolproof_guide_to_resurrecting_npcs/) to which I have found to restore and revert, and I have paraphrased it here:

1. Go to [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page), search for the NPC in question and record it's RefID
2. Launch the game, open console and type `Prid #RefID`, where `#RefID` is the number you wrote down This will make your console select the NPC as a target for future commands
3. Now type `moveto player`, making the NPC's dead body appear at your feet. This isn't strictly necessary but it'll allow you to immediately check whether the NPC has been revived and is functioning.
4. Now enter the `recycleactor` command. This will revive the NPC to its *default* status **including** inventory and area specific behavior

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Whiterun was never the same without Heimskr. He is back, annoying me as always.