# Skyrim Museum Quest in Dawnstar

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I knew that I had the quest to visit the Museum and get the quest, "Pieces of the Past" but when I looked through to find it it was gone.
 I looked through all the quests I had completed to see if I had failed it, but it was not there. Is it a bug or a glitch? 
I have killed a few guards in order to complete the dark brotherhood quest line but I don't think that I killed the owner of the Museum. Please provide an explanation if possible.

Comment: Well, the latter half of the Dark Brotherhood has you coming and going to/form Dawnstar on a regular basis, and in my experience that town is #1 on every single dragon's "Top 10 towns you must attack before the Dragonborn absorbs your soul" list. It is entirely plausible he died in a dragon attack as you were coming/going.

Comment: You should specify what platform you are using, so we can suggest actions for you

Answer (score 1):

To begin to answer this, you must establish the status of the NPC.

Moving yourself to that NPC's location would be a start

In the console enter

```
player.moveto XXXXXX
```

where

> xxxxxx

is *000240CE*, as found here the RefID for [Silus Vesuius](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silus_Vesuius).

After this, if you find that the specific NPC is dead, then you may resurrect the character and resume your questing. To resurrect and reset you the character in question, you should try the procedure listed here [resurrecting and resetting characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/bring-heimskr-back-to-preaching/174852#174852)