# Can I get Shadowmere if I've abolished The Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that [Shadowmere](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3AShadowmere) is a quest reward from the Dark Brotherhood questline. However, since I took the other route, killed Astrid when she visited me and got the quest to destroy the Brotherhood, which I later did (she can't tell me what to do!), I was wondering if it's still possible to get her horse some other way and not through the quest.

Comment: Are you playing on Console or PC? If you are playing on PC you could look for console commands to spawn Shadowmere. If you don't want to cheat then there is no other way to get him. For as far as i know at least.

Comment: I'm on PC, yes. I was looking for a non-cheating way to get the horse, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Without Cheats

The simple answer to your question, without cheats, is no.

The game is specifically scripted to give you Shadowmere once you have completed the Dark Brotherhoods quest related to the horse.

## With Cheats

With cheats, you can get Shadowmere however. First open up your console, and type:
`help Shadowmere`
It should come up with an "ID" for the NPC for Shadowmere, this is what you want to spawn in.

Then, type in:

```
player.placeatme 0009CCD <- Replace with the ID for Shadowmere, although I'm sure that is the ID.
```

Shadowmere will spawn in next to you, now select Shadowmere by clicking on him/her/it while the console menu is open. Now type in:

```
setownership
```

And Shadowmere should be yours.

## Conclusion

I understand that you want to play the game legitimately, and I'm like that too. But if you ***really*** want Shadowmere, perhaps a good way to "roleplay" it would be to say to yourself that you found him/her/it while destroying the hideout and tamed him/her/it? Up to you.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` console command: Using that command will instantly summon an instance (a copy) of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for *named* objects or NPCs. That command creates a new copy of an object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Comment: @galacticninja Correct, except Shadowmere doesn't exist before the quest is done. Creating a copy of something that doesn't exist, is *technically* creating it, until the original comes along, which it wont.

Comment: I believe named unique NPCs or creatures already exist in the game regardless of the status of their related quests. It is possible that they might be 'disabled', and one might need to use the `enable` console command to make them appear in the game. I won't recommend using `placeatme` at all for unique NPCs/creatures as they'll always create a duplicate, which aside from glitches, could cause save game bloat.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! I was hoping that I could potentially find a different quest that would give me access to her, but guess not. Still, thanks for clearing that up.