# Lydia goes to jail

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

She does not pass Go and collect 200 gold...

OK, jokes aside: I've noticed that **every time** I try to fast travel from Whiterun, Lydia disappears. When I use the `player.moveto` command, it takes me to Whiterun jail, where she peacefully sits in one of the cells.

At first it was funny, but now it gets a bit annoying.

Is there a possible solution to this little bug?

Comment: Do you have any [follower-related mods](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35312) installed?

Comment: No, nothing remotely related to followers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/3i6ywx/how_did_lydia_end_up_in_jail/), I think one of these is a likely cause for Lydia:

> You may have given her a stolen item or had her pick one up. I believe the non criminal AI is programmed to surrender (Brand Shei for example) so that may be the case. I've gone miles outside of Whiterun, stole something, and then had the guards bugging me. If Lydia "stole" something in the hold, the guards may have arrested her.

Another possibility:

> Happens to me with Lydia and Jordis. I think I was "trespassing" in the Jarl's quarters and I forget that they have pathetic sneak skill + wear heavy armor

Personally, I am thinking it is the second. I found [another thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/65963229) that mentioned something similar:

> IIRC followers can sometimes get arrested for trespassing. I forget exactly how you go about making this happen but I believe it involves fast travel.

Comment: Hmm, you might be on to something! I've taken all stolen items from her, fired her and get her back. So far it its fixed :)