# Why isn't Kharjo appearing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started skyrim as a khajit. I loved having kharjo as a follower before but now I can't find him anywhere. why is this and is it possible to still have him as a follower if so where can I find him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should read [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-do-i-find-my-follower-if-and-when-they-leave-me)

Kharjo's home (*spawn*) is **Ahkari's Caravan**, which roams the route between Dawnstar and Riften. The fastest way to find it is to fast-travel to the same two cities, in their route, and keep checking the stables. Alternatively you can advance time by using the Wait feature.

Eventually his caravan will come to you.