# Lydia hit with Wabbajack stick and disappeared!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven’t seen this exact question before in my search for an answer:

I was using my Wabbajack stick on a wolf and Lydia jumped in front of me to attack the wolf. I ended up blasting her with the stick and she disappeared. No body and no transformation that I could see. Is there any way to get her back from this? Might she have turned into an animal and run away unnoticed? If she died, wouldn’t her body still be there?

Answer (score 6):

The Wabbajack has a long list of effects:

- Fireball
- Thunderbolt
- Frost Rune
- Heal Other
- Disintegration
- Transformation

  - Summon effects: mudcrab, daedra, rabbit, chicken,    chicken that
    explodes after 20 seconds and transforms back.
  - Effect    canceled on hit: chicken, rabbit, dremora lord, or a random
    draugr.    Examples: draugr, goat, spectral, mudcrab
  - Effects that eliminates    target: sweetroll, fountain of septims or
    random books spawn.
  - Leveled    Dremora (common).
  - May spawn a rabbit behind target, which target will see as an enemy.
    Upon said rabbit de-spawning, the target will teleport to where the
    rabbit last was.
- Invisibility
- Summon enemy dremora to attack them.
- Ice Spike
- **Instant kill (ghostly remains; ghostly remains with sweetroll; normal
  remains; no body)**
- Fury
- Fear
- Drain stamina
- Paralyze
- Absorb health
- Target explodes, turns into ghostly remains and scattered gold and
  pitchforks. Taking the gold counts as stealing
- No effect
- Replace enemies with random amounts of cheese.
- Unspecified damage (no hit shader/FX)
- Causes an explosion, which is a unique destruction spell. This only
  damages the target, unlike other exploding spells.

As you can see one option is death without corpse.

If you play on PC there is a way to test/fix this.

open your console commands and move the chracter to you.
so type

```
Prid <refID>
```

With the redId of lydia being: "000A2C94" and follow that with

```
moveto player
```

If nothing happens she is probably dead, then u need to do the Prid command again followed by

```
resurrect 1.
```

If that doesn't work you can also

```
player.placeatme <BaseID> <#>
```

with Lydia's baseid being : "000A2C8E" and # being replaced by a 1

Comment: Another note: The Wabbajack will *never* kill an [essential](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Essential_NPCs) NPC. You can manually flag an NPC as essential using `setessential <BaseID> 1` - you must use the BaseID, not the RefID, or you can just pick one of the already-essential followers instead of Lydia. That won't bring a dead NPC back, of course.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` console command: Using that command will instantly summon a *copy* of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for *named* objects or NPCs, like Lydia. That command creates a new copy of an object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).